# Need help troubleshooting a Square Class, specifically the code?

Tags: java, class, constructor

I'm attempting to learn java, and I'm stuck on the 'Classes' section. They gave me a question and I'm not sure why it's wrong.

I've read it over lots and I don't understand why there are about 14 error messages? At all...

Here's the assignment:

```
  // You are to write the constructor specified for this Square class. The Square class 
  // has an instance variable of type double, side, which is the length of each side of 
  // the square. The javadoc has been provided for you to help you tell what you needs to
  // be done
 // 
 // HINT: Write the constructor for the class Square.
 // The constructor will take in a parameter of the type double
 // and assign that parameter to the instance variable side
```

And here's my code:

```
   public class Square(double side)

  private double side;

  /**
  * Constructor for objects of class Square
  * @param theSide the length of the side of this Square
  */
  public main(double theSide) {
  side = theSide;
  }
  /**
  * Gets the length of a side of this square
  * @return the side of this square
  */
  public double getSide()
  {
   return side;
  }


Compiler error: /tmp/codecheck.XNhW00Z3c8/Square.java:12: error: '{'    expected public class Square(double side) ^ /tmp/codecheck.XNhW00Z3c8/Square.java:12: error: ';' expected public class Square(double side) ^ /tmp/codecheck.XNhW00Z3c8/Square.java:31: error: reached end of file while parsing } ^ /tmp/codecheck.XNhW00Z3c8/Square.java:14: error: variable side is already defined in class Square private double side; ^
```

Comment: where is the error? please post the error

Comment: 14 errors and you can't be bother posting one of them?

Comment: Here are the errors, they're down to 4 now.

Comment: Compiler error: /tmp/codecheck.XNhW00Z3c8/Square.java:12: error: '{' expected public class Square(double side) ^ /tmp/codecheck.XNhW00Z3c8/Square.java:12: error: ';' expected public class Square(double side) ^ /tmp/codecheck.XNhW00Z3c8/Square.java:31: error: reached end of file while parsing } ^ /tmp/codecheck.XNhW00Z3c8/Square.java:14: error: variable side is already defined in class Square private double side; ^

Comment: Put the errors into your question, in a code block.

Comment: Okay, I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are actually giving parameter to the class. in java class should not have a parameter

look here

```
public class Square(double side)
```

the right way class

```
public class Square
{
    private double side;
    public Square(double theSide)
    {
        side=theSide;
    }
    public double getSide()
    {
        return side;
    }


}
```

another class

```
public class TestSquare
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Square square = new Square(25.00);
        System.out.println("Square sides:"+square.getSide());
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the parameter to hold all the code inside the class?

Comment: it's not allowed to have a parameter in the class header delete (double side) in the class header who thought you about it?

Comment: The only time anything akin to a parameter is in the class header is when using generics. E.g. `public class Node <T>`. @JolandaCarlsen

Comment: @abcOfJava It goes with the methods, so I assumed it would be like that in the classes. And I answered other questions like that and got it right

Comment: @JolandaCarlsen just delete it please

Comment: I did, and it removed 10 error messages. Sorry, I was just confused.

Comment: @JolandaCarlsen its allright what's the other error says?

Comment: I don't understand the first three but the fourth says:

Comment: variable side is already defined in class Square private double side.... Except I didn't put the type, so that means I just assigned it a new value, right?

Comment: @abcOfJava I put it in the code block, at another user's request.

Comment: @Jolanda can you edit your post with delete parameter in the class header also with the main class with the method of main

Comment: For sure! By the way, thank-you for your help thus far.

Comment: @JolandaCarlsen I have edited my answer for you try it that is what I am talking about

Comment: Oh. That actually makes so much more sense! Thanks! Now I also understand why it wouldn't @abcOfJava